# How to solve Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1.?

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Can't build react native app in android studio.
I tried:

1. Sync Project with Gradle Files, but I can't do it because of an
   error
2. File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart
3. Clear cache from $HOME/.gradle
4. Delete $HOME/.gradle
5. Change com.android.tools.build:gradle version on 2.3.0, because it's
   the latest version in this list
   (https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/android/tools/build/gradle/), but when I use `npx react-native init projectName`, used Android Plugin Version 4.1.2, but this version there isn't in this list.
   Also know the difference between Gradle, Android Gradle Plugin,
   Gradle Wrapper, already read https://developer.android.google.cn/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?hl=en. I tryied to use the latest Gradle v. 6.8.2 and Android Gradle Plugin v. 4.1.2, it also didn't help to build the project.
6. Change `distributionUrl` in
   projectName/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
7. Change in File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle use
   Gradle from Specified location and set C:/Gradle/gradle-6.8.2, it didn't help and left it at default
   I know there are exactly the same questions on stackoverflow and on github, but the solutions haven't helped.

Build output:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :react-native-settings
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

Now used:

- Gradle v. 6.5
- Android Gradle Plugin v. 4.1.2
- gradle-wrapper 6.5-all
- Android Studios 4.1.2
- Android SDK Platform: Android 10, 9, 8.1, 8.0, 7.1.1, 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Your google Maven library is missing. Rebuild project after adding it